# Can Visual Studio setup project (MSI) create registry keys under HKLM?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, registry, windows-installer

According to this page it's possible to create an MSI installer to install an office add-in for all users: [Deploying your VSTO add-ins to All Users (Saurabh Bhatia)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx). It says what to do but skims on some of the how. I'm trying to create an MSI that creates registry keys under HKLM instead of HKCU. I have a setup project in Visual Studio. Under the registry section, I moved the keys from HKCU to HKLM, but when I run the installer it doesn't seem to create any keys, though there's also no sign of any errors. Is it possible to get visual studio to create keys under HKLM using the GUI or does it have to be coded in a custom action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on a 32bit or 64bit windows?  Odds are you need to look under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\SYSWOW64 to see the 32bit registry keys.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I only thought to look where I said to create the keys, not a completely different place. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office...

Comment: No, that is exactly where you told it to put it. I'd suggest reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384235(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also read: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/09/office-2010-bitness-pain.html and http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2010/10/vsto-4-2010-lessons-learned.html